# Connect to two databases

Tags: python, mysql

I want to connect to two databases using Python and, later on, use tables from both of the databases. How can I do this? Is the following code correct?

```
con = mdb.connect(host=MY_HOST, user=MY_USER, passwd=MY_PASS, db1=MY_DB1, db2=MY_DB2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use tables from both databases". Do you want to join them in a single query? That's not possible.

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes,I want to join tableA from database1 and tableB from database2, both of the databases are on the same server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you don't specify the database in your `connect` call, you can write queries against multiple databases at once. The [documentation](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#some-mysql-examples) says that `db` is not required.

```
db = _mysql.connect('localhost', 'user', 'passwd')
```

then

```
SELECT u.*, i.* FROM db1.users u LEFT JOIN db2.items i ON u.id = i.user_id
```

**But** it'll only work if the two databases are on the same server.

Comment: is there a gain in doing it this way compared to my answer?

Comment: one connection vs two connections.

Comment: Why is one better than two? performance, memory, ease of use or just your good taste?

Comment: Two connections means two sockets open to your MySQL server. Selecting the db is like `USE thatdb` so you're by default into that one. If you plan to do queries among multiple databases at the same time it might be simpler to not choose one, it's really a matter of taste here. But two connections just aren't necessary. You can always do `cursor.exectue('USE otherDB')` if you like to switch among them.

Answer (score 9):

Just make two separate connections

```
con1 = mdb.connect (host=MY_HOST, user=MY_USER, passwd=MY_PASS, db1=MY_DB1)
con2 = mdb.connect (host=MY_HOST2, user=MY_USER2, passwd=MY_PASS2, db2=MY_DB2)
```

and use them independently just as you would when using one database.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1) Take the data into a pandas DataFrame and use it to create table in second server.

2) BCP out data from server1 and load it into second server

Answer (score -1):

The two (or more) connections can live in a single variable e.g. a dictionary. This becomes very handy if you want to  perform one operation on all the connections at once. For example closing all of them. Here's an example:

`connections = {
    'conn1': mdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db),
    'conn2': mdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db)
}`

You can retrieve each connection with its key:

`connections['conn1'].execute('SELECT ...')`

And you can close all the connections in one line:

`[conn.close() for key, conn in connections.items()]`

Comment: Cannot work, right? Missing single-quotes at `[conn1]`?!

Comment: @qräbnö I have corrected the mistake. I didn't focus too much on syntax. This was just a quick example.