# Should we connect to multiple database with same mongod server?

Tags: python, mongodb

Suppose, I want to connect multiple database with same mongod. So, it is feasible and good approach to follow? If yes, then how could I use it with python?

I have searched on different platforms like stackoverflow, gitflow but didnot got any answer for my question.

```
MongoSet = str(MongoConfig[mongohost]['replica_set'])
                MongoIp  = str(MongoConfig[mongohost]['ip'])
                MongoPort  = str(MongoConfig[mongohost]['port'])
                MongoAddress  = MongoIp + ":" + MongoPort
```

## TODO: Although the default behaviour, and explicitly set here, should be PRIMARY read preference,

```
#       see in mongod.log secondaryPreferred. Continue monitoring this in the context of database performance.

   from pymongo.read_preferences import ReadPreference
   MongoClient_i = MongoClient(MongoAddress, read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY)
   MongoClientSet.append(MongoClient_i)
```

Comment: If you're looking for high availability & durability then you'll connect with multiple mongod's hosted in different servers but consists of same data i.e; data redundancy. So mongoDB has a concept called Replication : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/index.html, You can look into it, If you're working on a POC then you can create a free cluster at mongoAtlas which does replication by itself(has 3 nodes by default) : https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas ,Just connect to that mongo cluster & that's it your mongoDB is up n ready, At anytime read&writes are to primary by default

Comment: Thanks @srinivasy for your response but I want to connect to different database which will have different data in their collection.

Comment: Ok, I was confused when you said same mongod, Do you mean by same mongod version ? then this should be python question !!

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But my question is "Is it good idea to connect with multiple databases in a single application for mongodb?"

Comment: yes you can connect to two different DB's from your application, there shouldn't be any issue with that, we actually do the same we would connect to two DB(live,batch) on need basis. Just create two separate connections and use those as needed. Check this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940368/connect-to-two-databases

Comment: But I have 2 different database with different collections which 
I want to use at same time. So I hope, It will not affect my performance/execution time .

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue, if you've proper connections in place.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @srinivasy